# Send variables from a thread inside a service to main activity

Tags: android

I have a location listener running on a separate Thread inside a service class like so:

```
public void onCreate() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        final Criteria locCriteria = new Criteria();
        locCriteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        locCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        locCriteria.setSpeedRequired(true);

        locThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(locCriteria, true);
                listener = new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        Log.i("Lat changed", String.valueOf(latitude));
                        Log.i("Lon changed", String.valueOf(longitude));
                    }
```

How can i send the cordinates back to the main activity class to have them displayed in a text view? Besides using a broadcast.

Comment: You can use a Looper and Handler or an AsyncTask instead of using Thread.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice How would i go ahead with the Looper and Handler implementation?

Comment: I suggest you start with Google. There are many tutorials online about both Looper/Handler and AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use my code

**Create an Interface like**

```
public interface Message {
void latitudeandlongitude(double lat,double log);
}
```

**Then in your Service Class**

```
public void oncreate()
{
    Message ms=new Activity();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
            {
                //pass the latitude and longitude value
                ms.latitudeandlongitude(50.264,96.856);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**Then in your Activity**

```
public class Activity implements Message {
String textview; //use findviewbyId in oncreate method
@Override
public void latitudeandlongitude(double lat, double log) {
    textview.setText("Your latitude "+lat+" Your longitude "+log);

    //System.out.println("Your latitude "+lat+" Your longitude "+log);
}
```

}

Comment: please correct the answer and also upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an instance of `LocationListener` to your service rather than implementing the listener there. For example:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private LocationListener locationListener;

    public MyService(LocationListener locationListener) {
        this.locationListener = locationListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Do your stuff
        // add this location listener where it needs to be
    }

}
```

Then, in your activity or fragment, you implement the `LocationListener` and handle the results as you wish.